# mssql order table with grouping

Tags: sql-server, sorting

I have two tables.
How to order this table example:

```
A B
A D
A C
A A
B C
B B
B D
C D
C B
C D
```

to this table (double sorting results):

```
A A
A B
A C
A D
B B
B C
B D
C C
C B
C D
```

Comment: The logic itself is not clear, and you should provide the code of what you tried so far, cause as it is it is impossible to help you.

Comment: `SELECT a.*, b.* from tablea a left join tableb b on (a.field = b.field) ORDER by a.field, b.field` - try this, its untested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this, might be useful :

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(1), col2 VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
('A', 'B'),
('A', 'D'),
('A', 'C'),
('A', 'A'),
('B', 'C'),
('B', 'B'),
('B', 'D'),
('C', 'D'),
('C', 'B'),
('C', 'C')

SELECT * FROM @table1
ORDER BY col1, CASE WHEN col1 = col2 THEN '!' ELSE col2 END
```

Note : I assumed that there is no exclamation mark in your 2nd column's data.

Comment: `CASE WHEN col1 = col2 THEN '!' ELSE col2 END` will  a a, b b, c c , then another

Comment: @Malenkymuk I ran this query in my ssms and it gives what is required. also check this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3241 . if this is not as you expect then I would suggest to add your logic of sorting in your question.

Comment: Sorry, did not seen `col1,`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not this:**

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
GROUP BY ColA, ColB
ORDER BY ColA, ColB
```